# JDBC / MYSQL: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, jdbc

With this code

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
```

I get the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at MyTest1.main(MyTest1.java:29)
```

I logged into the database using the command tool with root and no password. I was able to telnet to the database and I get this message

```
N
 5.5.17-log
           7{*Zj%u☻Ç§|tR}=Vz'L,6imysql_native_password"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be some problem with my MYSQL installation.  I uninstalled the AMP package I was using and installed XAMPP instead and it works.

Comment: What is that `AMP` package? How could I uninstall it? I'm using `xampp` for `php`, also I'd installed `mysql server` on my localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Even I also faced the same problem. But, in my application, I did one mistake like I forgot to give password. You can try to manually login to your MySQL and check what is the username and password you are using to log in. That same details you can use in the URL. Better to give database names also. As like below
For MySQL:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
```

In the above, you forgot to give the port number of MySQL. You can check once your MySQL has a port number or not. By default, MySQL port number is 3306. Better to create and use your own database.

If the above one is not working try for GRANT all privileges to user root on your user database. To grant all privileges below is the query,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

or else

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
```

Answer (score 0):

`'root'@'localhost'` is different from `'root'@'%'`. It may still be a permissions issue.

I suggest that you log in through the console, create a 'test'@'%' user with a password, and give it all permissions. You can learn how to do that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html).